# Existence of quasi-isomorphisms between complexes with same homology

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, chain-complexes

Consider an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ (or more specifically, **$R$-Mod**). Suppose $C_1$ and $C_2$ are chain complexes with componentwise isomorphic homology. What conditions must be imposed upon $\mathcal{A}$ (or $R$), or $C_1$ and $C_2$, for there to exist a quasi-isomorphism $\alpha: C_1 \to C_2$? Or, under what conditions, if any, is there necessarily an isomorphism $C_1 \cong C_2$ in $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})$?

I certainly expect existing conditions to be rare. If the answer is "there basically are none" then I'd like to see some good examples highlighting this too!

Comment: If $R$ is a field, then in fact it happens always.

Comment: Indeed, as [this answer states.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59390/when-is-a-quasi-isomorphism-necessarily-a-homotopy-equivalence) I'm hoping for possibly more general statements though, if they exist.

Comment: You're probably aware of this, but if $\mathcal{A}$ has Ext-dimension 1, then every bounded complex splits in the derived category, see e.g. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0GM4

Comment: @ Zhen Lin, is it true thought for sheaves of fields $\mathbb{F}_X$?